# c++ Overwriting an already defined variable

Tags: c++, pointers, overwrite

I have the following main function, creating a product of coefficients using pointers. It's only a small part of the project, which is used to create polynomials:

```
#include "header.h"
int main()
{
    TermProd x = TermProd( new Coeff(4), new Coeff(8));
    x.print(); cout << endl;
    x = TermProd( new Coeff(8), new Coeff(15));
    x.print(); cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

After testing, the overwriting seems to be working. But when I call the print on x, I get a segmentation fault. I have been trying and staring at it for quite a while now, but I can't figure out the real problem. Also my searches didn't result into the right direction so I decided to create a small code-snippet which reproduces the error.

My header.h file looks like:

```
class Term{
public:
    Term(){};
    virtual ~Term(){};
        virtual Term* clone() const = 0;
    virtual void print() const = 0;
};

class Coeff:public Term{
    int m_val; //by def: >=0
public:
    // Constructor
    Coeff();
    Coeff(int val = 1):m_val(val)
    // Copy constructor
    Coeff* clone() const{return new Coeff(this->val());}
    // Destructor
    ~Coeff(){}
    // Accessors
    int val() const{return m_val;} ;
    // Print
    void print() const{cout << m_val; }
};

class TermProd:public Term{
    TermPtr m_lhs, m_rhs;
public:
    // Constructor
    TermProd(TermPtr lhs, TermPtr rhs):m_lhs(lhs), m_rhs(rhs){ }
    // Copy constructor
    TermProd* clone() const
    {
        return new TermProd(m_lhs->clone(), m_rhs->clone());
    }
    // Destructor
    ~TermProd(){ delete m_lhs;delete m_rhs;}
    // Accessors
    Term* lhs() const { return m_lhs; }
    Term* rhs() const { return m_rhs; } 
    // Print
    void print() const
    {
        cout << "("; m_lhs->print(); cout << '*'; m_rhs->print(); cout << ")";
    }       
 };
```

Comment: Read this: [The rule of 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: @Michael it will generate a temporary object which will be assigned to the first one.

Answer (score 6):

Note here you are not overwriting the `x` variable but instead assigning to it.  This will invoke the default `operator=` for your type which roughly causes the following code to be executed

1. The constructor `TermProd::TermProd(TermPtr, TermPtr)` is executed
2. The values `m_lhs` and `m_rhs` are copied into the value `x`
3. The destructor for the value created in step #1 is now run and `m_lhs` and `m_rhs` are deleted

At this point you have a real problem.  After step #2 both the value `x` and the temporary value created in step #1 shared the same `m_lhs` and `m_rhs` values.  The destructor at step #3 deletes them yet `x` still has a reference to them which is now effectively pointing at dead memory

In order to fix this problem you will need to add your own `operator=` which correctly handles the assignment semantics.  For example

```
TermProd& operator=(const TermProd& other) {
  if (&other != this) {
    delete m_lhs;
    delete m_rhs;

    m_lhs = other.m_lhs->clone();
    m_rhs = other.m_rhs->clone();
  }
  return *this;
};
```

In order to be correct for all scenarios you'll also need to add a proper copy constructor

```
TermProd::TermProd(const TermProd& other) :
  m_lhs(other.m_lhs->clone()),
  m_rhs(other.m_rhs->clone())
{

}
```

Really though to make this extremely simple you should consider using `std::shared_ptr<Term>` as the value for `TermPtr`.  It's a pointer that will make the sharing work without all of the above mentioned overhead

Comment: Your assignment operator should check if you assign to yourself, and in that case typically do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

You are not following the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)**.
The destruction of temporary variables created during the function calls by calling the implicit copy constructor `delete`s the allocated pointer member.

You need to provide your own copy constructor and copy assignment operator which will make a deep copies of the dynamically allocated pointer member.

Answer (score 3):

You don't provide a copy constructor. You have a `clone` method, that the comment say is the copy constructor, but it isn't.

Try something like:

```
TermProd(TermProd const & other)
  m_lhs(other.m_lhs->clone()),
  m_rhs(other.m_rhs->clone())
{
}
```

And likewise for the other classes.

*Update* As pointed out in the comments, you will also need an *assignment operator*.

```
TermProd & operator=(TermProd const & other)
{
  if (this != &other)  // Check for assignment to self.
  {
    delete m_lhs;
    delete m_rhs;
    m_lhs = other.m_lhs->clone();
    m_rhs = other.m_rhs->clone();
  }
  return *this;
}
```

Comment: And then `clone()` can be simplified to `return new TermProd(*this);`.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem here.  The faulty code is the assignment which will invoke `operator=` not the copy constructor

Comment: You'll also need a copy-assignment operator, `TermProd & operator=(TermProd const &);`

Comment: @JaredPar: Both *could* be a problem here - the first line does a copy, which may or may not be elided.

Comment: @MikeSeymour yes you're correct about that. I read right past the copy and saw it as a direct ctor call